# why is the word 'mapping' missing in this line of code?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm learning how to use ggplot functions, all this time I've been learning that mapping=aes(x=x variable, y=y variable), but in the code below when using the facet_wrap function, the word mapping is completely missing but the code still works. I am not sure why? Can anyone explain please?

```
`ggplot(data=penguins, aes(x=flipper_length_mm, y=body_mass_g))+
  geom_point(aes(color=species))+
  facet_wrap(~species)`
```

Not sure why the word 'mapping' is missing from the syntax

Comment: Try looking at the documentation (`?ggplot` in the console). If you provide arguments in the same order as the function definition, you do not need to provide argument names. Since `mapping` comes second in the function definition, and it comes second in the arguments to `ggplot()` in your code, there is no need to provide the argument name. You could similarly write `ggplot(penguins)` instead of `ggplot(data = penguins)`

Comment: @knitz3 your comment would make a good answer

Comment: Try removing the `facet_wrap` first and tell us the output. It could be something with the data. Also show us the actual error message.

Comment: FYI, here's the point in the `R for Data Science` text where they explain the switch from using `mapping = aes(...)` for pedagogical reasons to just `aes(...)` which is more concise and far more prevalent. https://r4ds.had.co.nz/exploratory-data-analysis.html#ggplot2-calls